# Problema com includes usando urls amigáveis

Tags: php, url-amigável

Estou com um problema que já está me deixando doido, estou usando urls amigáveis em um sisteminha que estou fazendo e os arquivos css,js etc não estão carregando, já vi vários casos aqui que isso acontece por causa de não colocar o caminho de forma correta, mas isso eu já concertei e todo página eu estou usando incluo um arquivo chamado config.php que tem o diretório base e a url do site armazenados em variaveis:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $url_base; ?>/painel/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Arquivo config.php:

```
<?php
$path_base = dirname(__FILE__);
$url_base = "http://localhost/iesav2";
```

Arquivo .htaccess está assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^error404/?$ 404.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^adm_usuarios/?$ adm_usuarios.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^adm_usuarios/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ adm_usuarios.php?nivel=$1&pesquisa=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^adm_usuarios/([0-9]+)/?$ adm_usuarios.php?nivel=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^adm_usuarios/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ adm_usuarios.php?pesquisa=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index_friend.php
```

O arquivo index_friend.php onde as paginas são direcionadas está assim:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once '../config.php';
//Pega toda url apos o dominio e transforma em array
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
//Pega diretório base e transforma em array
$path = explode("/", dirname(__FILE__));
//Compara a url com diretório base e remove o que não precisa
$url = array_diff($url, $path);
//Reseta indices do array
$url = array_values($url);
//Remove extensoes do nome do arquivo
$url[0] = str_replace(array('.php','.html'), '', $url[0]);
//Nome do arquivo requisitado
$file = $url[0].'.php';
//Se o arquivo existir então faz include para dentro
if(file_exists($file)){
    include ($path_base.'/painel/'.$file);
}else{ // Se não exibe error
    include ($path_base.'/painel/404.php');
}
```

Sem usar a pagina index_friend.php e acessando diretamente por exemplo http://localhost/iesav2/painel/login os arquivos carregam normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Não é necessário colocar url no link para incluir.

Basta deixar no modelo abaixo:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/painel/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Daí você olha no código fonte do navegador para ver se realmente está redirecionando para o arquivo css.